# Word sometimes bold and sometimes not in listing

Tags: listings

I would like to write a listing in which the same word appears in some cases in bold and in some other cases not.
In particular the listing is structured as a set ok key-value pairs, as follows:

**key1:** value1
**key2:** value2
...

The same word could appear as a key or as a value. I'd like to have all the keys (and colon) in bold, and the values not.

How could I achieve this result in a listing?

Thank yoy very much!

Comment: and that listing should be only key=value pairs?

Comment: I think an MWE would be a good idea for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If that listing should only contain key=value pairs, why do you need a listing at all? Couldn't that just be a `description` environment?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % allows more control over list formatting

\newcommand*\keyvallistingFORMAT[1]{\normalfont\textbf{#1}:}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[format=\keyvallistingFORMAT]
  \item[key1] value1
  \item[key2] value2
  \item[key3] value3
  \item[value1] key1
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

If you'd like a more concise input format, you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % allows more control over list formatting
\usepackage{expkv}

\newcommand\keyvallisting[1]
  {%
    \begin{description}[format=\keyvallistingFORMAT]
      \ekvparse\keyvallistingKEY\keyvallistingKEYVAL{#1}
    \end{description}%
  }
\newcommand*\keyvallistingKEY[1]{\item[{#1}]}
\newcommand*\keyvallistingKEYVAL[2]{\item[{#1}] #2}
\newcommand*\keyvallistingFORMAT[1]{\normalfont\textbf{#1}:}

\begin{document}
\keyvallisting{key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3,value1=key1}
\end{document}
```

Both will result in

[image]

Comment: Actually the key-value pairs are part of a bigger listing. For this reason I cannot use a description. However thank you very much for the suggestion!